# Android Persistent Storage

Tags: android, json, sqlite, local-storage, storage

I have read through the [Android Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and I have a question that I haven't been able to find the answer to:

**Should I use SQLite to store my data or should I use a JSON object that is written to a file?**

**Requirements:**
Store (up to) a few hundred instances of the same object. Each instance will be somewhat complex, storing reference to images, smaller objects, etc. The data will be stored locally, with the option of cloud backup.  All the data will be loaded on startup and saved when manipulated by the user.

The reason I ask this is because I don't have a lot of data to store - for a SQLite database there will probably never be more than a few 100 rows, which makes me think SQL is overkill.

Also, exporting my data to a JSON file will allow me to easily import/export from different device platforms (I already do this on iOS).

Or, maybe there's a better option? If there was an `NSCoding` type library for Android I would probably use that.

Any opinions are helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a broad question and can lead to several opinionated answers. You are the best person to answer this question because only you know what data you will be storing.

Comment: I guess I'm more wondering if JSON is a valid persistent storage format? Or if I'm going to run into performance issues if I need to store an array with a few 1000 values.

Comment: any one sir, you sqlite, who-knows-database  etc.. just make sure you can use it efficiently etc, well for performance there are soo many places you can hit up not just your data storing and retrieval so free world Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the presented so far, storing in files will be more advantageous.

Considering that each "unit" is less than 16 attributes, a json file with short identifiers will likely generate a larger file representation than the SQL representation equivalent.
However, the local file manipulation will allow for easier interactions, as well as easier backing up/down.
Also, the File class is simple enough to generate less issues when compared to SQL.
Finally, given the choices, you are going to have to evaluate the operations used.

If you are going to compare the data, then SQL is likely to go faster, but if you are just inputting/outputting each data as a separate object, than files are going to be as fast as SQL.

Finally, please, particionate your objects, do not create just 1 file with all the info.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm wondering, is there an easy way to export a SQL database to JSON? Or, more accurately, export a Java object to JSON?  If so, it might be beneficial in the long run to use a database.

Comment: @cohenadair I am un-aware of a good program that outputs databse to json, since their rules are different. What I usually do, is have a "toJsonFile(**some rule**)" basically, I would read some data from server, and particionate into files (like output0.json ... output999.json) this is good when I have too much data, I can use bad end computers to keep transfering the data in batches (also, phone devices, etc.)...

Comment: Thank you; I think I'm going to go try this route since it will make importing/exporting from/to other platforms much easier. Plus I already export my iOS data to a JSON file for backup.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read through the Android Storage Options and I have a question
>   that I haven't been able to find the answer to:
>
> Should I use SQLite to store my data or should I use a JSON object
>   that is written to a file?

You need to analyse your requirement again.

> maybe there's a better option?

It depends upon your requirement.
if Your requirement is fixed to simply storing and retrieving then you can have a look on [tinnyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo), which is basically using the `SharedPreferences` as storage mechanism. But if you need case base based selection/query of data then you should go with `SQLite`.

Comment: I have added requirements to the question. I won't need to use any queries; it's a matter of loading all data on startup and saving the data as it's manipulated.